# Show additional information with onmouseover a image

Tags: javascript

I have three Images on a Website, and i want to Show an specific Information for every single  Image using onmouseover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="de"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>AJAX</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/stil.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/ajaxeinsendeaufgabe2.js"></script> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
       <h1>Zusatzinformationen</h1> 
       <table> 
           <tr> 
               <td><img class="img" src="img/b1.jpg" /></td> 
               <td id="info0"></td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td><img class="img" src="img/b2.jpg" /></td> 
               <td id="info1"></td> 
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
               <td><img class="img" src="img/b3.jpg"/></td> 
               <td id="info2"></td> 
           </tr> 
       </table> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

I Need now help for the external Javascript. How i can Code the Elements by ID in order to Show using onmouseover, for example, the info0 text for the first Image, the info1 text for the second Picture and info2 text for the third Picture?

Maybe this way

```
     var resOb = new XMLHttpsRequest ();
    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByTagName ("img");
function sndReq(0){
    document.getElementById ("info0");
  }
   }  
  switch(i) { 
  case 0: 
 resOb.open('get', 'info0.txt', true); 
  break; 
  case 1: 
 … 
 } 
 resOb.onreadystatechange = function() { 
 handleResponse(i); 
 } 
 document.getElementbyID("info0").innerHTML
 ...
```

Sorry, but i have less skills in javascript

Comment: would be javascript not php

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, of course

Comment: i have a tip for you: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Need more details about how it should work. Maybe an example site.

Comment: you could do this entirely with css and no javascript btw - hidden spans/divs with the content that gets revealed on mouse events

Comment: I access to the Images with document.getElementsbyName, and after every call back a function like sndReq(0)

Comment: @RamRaider I must do it with Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this simple thing jquery

```
<div class="someDiv">
    <p>Click me here for mouseover image</p>
</div>
<img style="display:none" class="image" src="http://imgur.com/a/63gbF"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(".someDiv").hover(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        $(".image").css({"position":"absolute","left":event.clientX ,"top":event.clientY }).show();    
    });    
});

//end movement with click on the div.
$(document).bind("click",function(){
    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
    $(".image").hide();
});
</script>
```

**In javascript**

```
<style>
#parent #popup {
  display: none;
}

#parent:hover #popup {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">
This is the main container.
<div id="popup" style="display: none"><img src="http://imgur.com/a/63gbF"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById('parent');
e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```